Unclear derivation for the PPO method
page 209, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4842-9606-6


How is eq. (11.4) derived from eq (11.2). Could someone show step-by step derivation?

The first line of equation (11.4) is copied from equation (11.2) where the definition of your book's advantage function $\hat A_{\pi}(s_t,a_t)$ plays a key role and it seems you have no problem for this.
The second line could be understood first rewriting the expectation wrt the random trajectory $\tau$ under the new policy $\pi'$ as the joint expectation of the random state $s$ and the random action $a$ following the distribution of $d_{\pi'}$ and $\pi'$, respectively, since any reward trajectory is jointly decided by state and action with the environment's transition dynamics which doesn't effect advantage function at all. The author also explicitly gives the definition of $d_{\pi}$ (thus $d_{\pi'}$ implicitly) at the end of your quote which is the expected discounted probability distribution of visiting any state $s$ under the policy $\pi$. So now with the new joint expectation expression there's no more different step-wise $\hat A_{\pi}(s_t,a_t)$, but only the unified $\hat A_{\pi}(s,a)$. Therefore in terms of mathematical step, we can rewrite the RHS of the first line as $\mathbb{E}_{s \sim d_{\pi'}, a \sim \pi'}[\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t \hat A_{\pi}(s,a)]=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \gamma^t \mathbb{E}_{s \sim d_{\pi'}, a \sim \pi'}[\hat A_{\pi}(s,a)]=\frac{1}{1-\gamma}\mathbb{E}_{s \sim d_{\pi'}, a \sim \pi'}[\hat A_{\pi}(s,a)]$
Further due to the commutative property of expectation and infinite sum under certain condition of absolutely convergent series according to Fubini-Tonelli theorem of measure theory and bear in mind that expectation is nothing but a type of weighted sum. Then it's obvious that you can use elementary geometric series formula regarding the discount factor $\gamma$ to get the leading coefficient.
The third line of equation (11.4) is due to the idea of importance sampling since there may already be samples generated by the old policy which we want to take advantage of.

Could you please write your explanations as a step-by-step mathematical derivation?

I've added step-by-step mathy derivation as requested for the critical 2nd line, other steps seem trivial based on my described ideas. Lmk if you need additional clarification.
